# jquery Icon Class Toggle on Click

Tags: jquery

When I click on 'arrow' icon, it toggles between classes 'up' and 'down', but since there are a lot of 'arrow' icons, when I click on another one, I would like the previous one to lose the class 'up'(if it has one) before adding it to the clicked 'arrow'. My JQUERY code seems to work fine except for this case scenario:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqtLj.png)

*click arrow ('up' class is added)

*click another arrow ('down' class added to previous, 'up' added to clicked arrow)

*click another arrow ('down' class added to previous, the clicked arrow disappears)

My code:

```
$('.accordion').click(function() {
  if($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-angle-down')){
      $('i').addClass('fa-angle-down');
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');
} else {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down');
}
});
```

Any logic flaws in my function code.?

Comment: what are the arrows for?

Comment: For the indication of the dropdown content.

Comment: what is the case scenario? We can't get it through image. Add HTML part and scenario description to your question to make it clear.

Comment: @rukasu are you using bootstrap dropdown? because you could change the icon on the dropdown event instead on click of the icon parent

Comment: The case scenario is described before the code. The image was only to illustrate the arrows, not helpful for the actual solution.

Comment: @Cr1xus no, I'm not using bootstrap dropdowns.

Comment: @rukasu ok. so your html for the arrow is something like: `<button class='accordion'><i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i></button>` ?

Comment: In this case, adding some html would also help.  It's likely you just need to assign your event to the correct element rather than the parent element or use `event.eventTarget`

Comment: @Cr1xus yes, exactly like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution with a help of @Cr1xus approach.

```
$('.accordion-question').click(function() {
  if($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-angle-down')){
      $('i').addClass('fa-angle-down');
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up');
} else {
  $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-angle-down').removeClass('fa-angle-up');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.accordion').click(function() {
  if($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-angle-down'))
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up');
  else 
      $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-angle-down').removeClass('fa-angle-up');
});
```

Comment: Weird. There's an error of an unexpected token 'else' in your code snippet, so it doesn't run.

Comment: ops sorry missed a )

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to remove 'fa-angle-up' from an arrow when I click on another one.

Comment: @rukasu so you want all the arrows, BUT the one you click.

Comment: @rukasu can you provide html?

Comment: Yes, I want all the open arrows to close(if there are any). Except for the one I click on, obviously.

Comment: ` <button class="accordion"><h3 class="accordion-question">Question<i 
    class="fa fa-angle-down fa-lg icon-float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </h3></button>
              <div class="panel">
                <p>Answer</p>
              </div>`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZI would've, but the answer was not correct. I was waiting to edit it (with comments too) for html to be provided